# R: Underlying Code for Silhouette Plot?

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I work with the Silhouette Plot from R Package 'Cluster' and want to relabel the statistics shown on the righthand side of the plot (e.g., clusters should be denoted by 'c' instead of 'j').

Can anyone please provide me the underlying R Code so that I can adjust the labeling? Or are there further plot parameters that allow for adjustments?

Thank you very much for your help.

Florian

Comment: This question is unclear (you don't show any code) and appears to be asking for the code underlying a function, which is easily found by just typing the function name into your R console.

Answer (score 4):

Find all methods for `"silhouette"` class:

```
> methods(class = "silhouette")
[1] plot.silhouette*    summary.silhouette*

Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

To get code:

```
getAnywhere(plot.silhouette)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer!!! That was exactly the function that I looked for!!!!